# When i Try to write row and column in an excel sheet using a loop only the last loop values gets print

Tags: java, excel, xssf

I want to print all the rows and column in my excel, but it always print the last column alone(i.e. whatever writes in the last loop).

Is there a way to get print all the values and not overwrite the excel again and again. below is the program i used
please let me know where i have mistaken.

I want the 1st Column get printed first and then the 2nd column. Don't want the row to get print first

```java
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception  {
        XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet spreadsheet=wb.createSheet();
        FileOutputStream fos=null;

        for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                Row row=spreadsheet.createRow(i);
                Cell value=row.createCell(j);
                value.setCellValue(i+" Test");
                fos=new FileOutputStream("Testexcel.xlsx");
                wb.write(fos);
            }
        }

        wb.close();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

#### This is the result I got

[image: This is the result I got]

#### This is the result I want

[image: This is the result I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this code

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception  {
        XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet spreadsheet=wb.createSheet();
        FileOutputStream fos=null;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            Row row=spreadsheet.createRow(i);
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                Cell value=row.createCell(j);
                value.setCellValue(i+" Test");
                
            }
        }
       fos=new FileOutputStream("Testexcel.xlsx");
       wb.write(fos);

        wb.close();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

---

ok for you case try this and get back to me i cant test this. cause i don't have the source code.

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception  {
    XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet spreadsheet=wb.createSheet();
    FileOutputStream fos=null;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        Row row=spreadsheet.createRow(i);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
         for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
           Row row = spreadsheet.getRow(i);
            Cell value=row.createCell(j);
            value.setCellValue(i+" Test");
            }
        }
   fos=new FileOutputStream("Testexcel.xlsx");
   wb.write(fos);

    wb.close();
    fos.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: do accept the answers if it worked so that people can get to the answer quickly or the community understands that the question has been answered so they can search for other questions. you can accept the answers by clicking on the tick you get next to the answers

Comment: Hi praneeth, Actually i wanted the 1st column to print first and then 2nd column.. the solution you gave prints it row vice.. 

Can you please help me out here a little bit more and give a solution to that.

Comment: hey, @Rohitkumar have you tested it?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the comments as well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet spreadsheet = wb.createSheet();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
        XSSFRow xssfRow = spreadsheet.createRow(row); // row should be created only once per iteration
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
            XSSFCell value = xssfRow.createCell(col);
            value.setCellValue(row + " Test"); // changes as per your need
            // value.setCellValue("("+ row + "," + col + ") Test");

        }
    }

    fos = new FileOutputStream("Testexcel.xlsx"); // this should be done at the end, not within the loop
    wb.write(fos);
    wb.close();
    fos.close();

}
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav, Actually i wanted the 1st column to print first and then 2nd column.. the solution you gave prints it row vice.. Can you please help me out here a little bit more and give a solution to that.